# Where did the Datagrid go in Silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight-5.0

As the question asks, does anyone know which namespace and/or assembly the Datagrid went in Silverlight 5?

It used to be in the toolkit, but now its just vanished. All searches in Google and in the documentation/assemblies reveal nothing...maddening!!

Any help is appreciated.

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it's not gone anywhere, I've got it in my SL5 project with no changes from SL4.

Comment: What version of the Toolkit are you using?

Comment: I expected to find it in SL5 dec 2011 toolkit, but apparently its been moved into the Core Silverlight dlls. The namespace remains the same however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)

It is there. Here is the download link: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/78435

It is for Silverlight 5. The `DataGrid` is in the `System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll` assembly and on `System.Windows.Controls.Data` namespace.

If the DataGrid do not appear on the toolbox, try this:
Add a reference to System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll
Add on your UserControl:

```
<UserControl...
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"/>


<sdk:DataGrid/>
```

Comment: Yes, DataGrid is in System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll assembly located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client folder.